# Too many declined flags

Tags: support, flag-ban

I want to flag a question few minutes ago, but I couldn't. This is the screen

[image]

> Too many of your recent flags have been declined-

So I clicked to *review* , and I saw this;

[image]

2 declined counts too many? I'm wondering what to do now I don't want to change my recent flags. Also only 2 declined flags is too many?

Comment: @gnat I don't think my answer is there.

Comment: 2 declined : 6 helpful => should trigger suspension [according to criteria laid out here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/165773) if all 8 flags were cast in one week: "If at least 25% of your flags from the past 7 days were declined, you're blocked from flagging anything. Depending on when and how those declined flags were cast, this block could last for as little as a day, and won't ever be longer than a week..."

Comment: @gnat Can you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/4447887 8 flags, 6 helpfull. What can I do now?

Comment: no, this page is visible only to you and to diamond moderators (I am a regular user). I can see it only on [your screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cG5aR.jpg). What you can do now is take a break for a day or two (a week at most), take a closer look at flags that went well and bad and ponder what you could do better when suspension ends, to avoid falling in it next time

Comment: @gnat It's so annoying... Just 2 little declined flags :-(

Comment: could happen to everyone. If you think of it, this is necessary protection against _truly_ abusive folks. Or against those who don't want to learn. And, it's not as annoying really. Few years ago I was suspended for 2 weeks from suggesting edits. At first it felt bad but in the long run turned out very helpful. Looking back I am now grateful to reviewers who rejected my stuff back then because it helped me learn how to do it better